# Allocator that manages a single block of memory

Tags: c++11, boost, memory-management, allocator, memory-pool

Due to system limitations, suppose that I can only allocate memory from a heap once (for example with `std::allocator` or some other more general C++11 compliant allocator).

This single allocation will take a large memory block. 
Then I want to use containers and dynamic memory but all restricted to the previously allocated block of memory.

I managed to write very simple allocator that incrementally "gives" memory  shifting a pointer. 
In this allocator `deallocate` is a no-op, and memory from the block is not returned to the block. 
One can obviously do better than this.
In other words, I want a managed heap.

Reusing this block memory in a sequence is a hard problem because one needs to *manage discontinuous free segments, defragmentation, (optional) thread-safety, etc.*

**What is the name of this pattern?** For some time I though that this was a pool allocator but it seem that that refers to something else (reusing small objects).

**What features or standard libraries of C++ can I use either implement and administer such allocation or at least build my own with little effort?**

I expected to find something in Boost.
But Boost.Pool is something else and it looks like something like this is implemented for a specific purpose in Boost.Interprocess but it doesn't seem to be easy to use and I have a hard time to understand it outside their prototypical use (such a interprocess shared memory.)

Otherwise, the closest thing I found is this https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/pool/doc/interfaces/pool_alloc.html , but it seems that `::new` can be called several times.

Example code:

```
int main(){
    UserBlockAllocator<double> a(new double[1000], 1000); 
    {
        std::vector<double, UserBlockAllocator<double>> v0(600, a);
    } // v0 returns memory to block managed by a
    std::vector<double, UserBlockAllocator<double>> v1(600, a);
    std::vector<double, UserBlockAllocator<double>> v2(600, a); //out of memory
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This pattern is referred to as **arena allocator** or **stack allocator**. If I understand the `std::pmr` stuff correctly, a [`std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/monotonic_buffer_resource) is related to that, but I have never tried that.

With those keywords you find something, but I have no experience with the tools.

Note that it is easy to succesfully deallocate the *most recent* allocation.

A powerful pattern is the composition of allocators as described in an entertaining talk by Andrei Alexandrescu at CppCon 2015. If you want to build your own tool, you might consider the combination of a `FreeListAllocator` ([43:18](https://youtu.be/LIb3L4vKZ7U?t=43m18s)) on top of your `StackAllocator` ([35:42](https://youtu.be/LIb3L4vKZ7U?t=35m42s)). This way, you may solve the problem how to *manage discontinous free segments* (as you describe it).

Comment: I assume that it is called "stack allocator" because the allocator (not the memroy) can be in the stack.  Also, monotonic_buffer_resource seems to work with std::allocator only.

Comment: @alfC: I am not sure where the name "stack allocator" originates from. Have you noticed that a "stack allocator" can deallocate its most recent allocation only? Maybe this behavior is what the "stack" refers to.

Comment: @alfC: As far as I understand it, `std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource` is supposed to be used with [`std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/polymorphic_allocator). These `std::pmr` additions from C++17 seem to be designed for very few and specific applications. I have not experienced with them yet.

Comment: @alfC: It's called a stack allocator because its behavior is much like a stack: an allocation is a "push" operation. There's just no equivalent to a "pop".

Comment: @NicolBolas, yes, I understand that now. I was looking at the time something that would implement a `stack_allocator` (or something more advanced) on top of any existing allocator and pointer (not only `std::allocator` and `T*`). I couldn't find one around so I implemented one myself as best as I could.

Comment: @alfC: But `monotonic_buffer_resource` is a stack allocator. Why implement it yourself?

Comment: @NicolBolas, becasue the allocator I am trying to use behind `monotonic_buffer_resource` (or the stack allocator) is one that doesn't return a `T*` (on `allocate`). Perhaps I am trying to build the stack allocator at the wrong level of abstraction.

Comment: @alfC: `monotonic_buffer_resource` doesn't deal in `T*`s; it deals in `void*`s, just like its parent class `memory_resource`. `polymorphic_allocator<T>` deals in `T*`s, but that's something you use with an Allocator-aware construct, and it wraps the `memory_resource` interface in an Allocator-aware way.

Comment: @NicolBolas, yes, `void*` which is even a level of abstraction below. I should have say "becasue the resource I am trying to use behind monotonic_buffer_resource (or the stack allocator) is one that doesn't return a `void*` (but a fancy_ptr<void>)".